# Python: list comprehension behavior for one/many elements 2D arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, numpy, list-comprehension

I have a problem with the behavior of list comprehension for 2D arrays created with numpy: The behavior is dependent of the length of the list:

```
import numpy as np

oneElement = np.ones([2,3]) # one super tiny images in a list
twoElement = [oneElement, oneElement] # two super tiny images in a list

print([E.shape for E in twoElement]) # here E represents an img
>>>> [(2, 3), (2, 3)]
print([E.shape for E in oneElement]) # here E represents only a row (of an img)
>>>> [(3,), (3,)]
```

As you see, the first `print()` printed the dimensions of an image. That is, because the `E` is representing an 2D array, or an full image respectively. This is the behavior I want!

The second list comprehension however, only returns single rows. I assume because "rows" is the only thing to iterate over, here.

Ultimately, I (always) want the first behavior, iterating over full images, not single rows, independent of the number of images in the list. Is there a way to "tell" the list comprehension to do so? Or do I always have to include a `if (type(twoElement) is list):` beforehand?

That will make my source code quite ugly, because I have many such comprehensions, but I can not guarantee that there is always more than one image in the list...

Thanks for advice!

**EDIT/UPDATE**:
BSM solved the problem (or at least specifing where to problem lies) by pointing out, that `oneElement` is *not a list but an ndarray*.
Iterating with list-comprehension in the fashion I want it it for `oneElement` can be solved by adding a further pair of squared-brackets:

```
oneElement = [np.ones([2,3])]
print([E.shape for E in oneElement])
>>>> [(2, 3)]
```

Comment: You keep referring to `list`, but `oneElement` is not a list, it's an ndarray.  What prevents you from using `[np.ones([2,3])]`, which is a list of one element?

Comment: As DSM mentioned, you can create an one-element list containing `oneElement`. Otherwise, why not creating a `print_shape` function to check only once the type on input (`list` or `ndarray`)?